# What are some general chemistry textbook with good problems?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I’m currently in a General Chemistry course and am wondering if you guys can recommend me a textbook or resource where I can find good problems to work through and further my understanding. We’re currently using Oxtoby but I find the problems to be a bit straightforward.